# how to block node js server address and port used for third party

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io

I  have `phpmyadmin,  PHP , nodeJS` run on the same server and  i use below code to get data from nodejs to my php website. So anyone can copy that code and add to some HTML page and chek what my nodejs server sending on this port.
**Is there any way to block this nodejs server address use outside from my server??**.

**This  is client side code**

```
var socket  = io.connect('http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8000');
socket.on('device', function (data) {
var   commentData = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(commentData);
   var  cID  =  commentData.data.cID;
   var  dID  =  commentData.data.dID;
   var  status  =  commentData.data.status;
if(status =='online'){
    $("#"+cID+dID).attr('class','online-icon');
}
 if(status =='offline'){
        $("#"+cID+dID).attr('class','offline-icon');
    }

});
```

**This  is server side code**

```
var express = require('express');
var socket  = require('socket.io');
var http    = require('http').Server(app);
var request = require('request');
var app     = express();
app.use(express.static('views'));
app.set('views', 'views/product'); 
app.use(express.static('./public'));
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var server     = app.listen(8000, function () {
});
var io         = socket(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 io.sockets.emit('device', 'test');
});
```

Comment: That's what a firewall is for

Comment: @GordonM Good sir can you bit explain it??

Comment: What do mean by `client side` ?

Comment: @BrahmaDev that mean user browser  ( chrome , firefox)

Comment: If I am getting this right, the chosen answer is not going to work, see his last comment on the answer. That is going to block anyone from accessing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to block this nodejs server address use outside from my server?

Networked computers typically have at least two network interfaces: The "local" one and the network-facing one. If you have services that only need to talk to each other on the server, bind the service to the local one (`localhost` aka `127.0.0.1`).

You're using `express`, so you'd do this in your [`listen`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen) call, which is identical to Node.js's own [`Server.listen`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen). E.g.:

```
var server     = app.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1', function () {
// -------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

or for IPv6:

```
var server     = app.listen(8000, '::1', function () {
// -------------------------------^^^^^^^
});
```

Then no other host on the network will be able to connect to that service.

Comment: Good sir if i add that modification to my server side. what do i need to change in client-side code? can I use same   `127.0.0.1` for client side??

Comment: @1323254365: That's right, yes (or `::1` if using IPv6), since you only want to communicate within the machine. (Apologies, btw; host goes after port, not before. I've fixed the answer.)

Comment: Sir in browser side (client side) do I need to put original server IP Address? or can I use like( localhost or 127.0.0.1)?

Comment: @1323254365: Again: Yes. The browser **is** running on the same machine, right? Because your question is *"Is there any way to block this nodejs server address use outside from my server?"*

Comment: Thank for your help, Sir. :)